# IIS Memory Leak in 64 bit only mode

Tags: iis, memory-leaks, 32bit-64bit

I am having an issue where w3wp.exe is gaining around 100 meg per page load on a specific page (not entire site). The page is not that memory intensive and should not require so much memory.

I modified a single setting, "Enable 32-bit Applications" and set it to true and now the leak is gone, however I need to understand why this might be happening. It is happening only on one server, the other servers we test on do not see this issue. When Enable 32-bit Applications is disabled (false), the results from the ANTS memory profiler are attached below.  Does anyone have any idea what's going on? Please note the only thing growing is "Unused Memory" / "Free Space" [image: Baseline snapshot]

[image: 1st Page Load]

[image: 3rd Page Load]

Answer (score 0):

Can you go into the list of classes and sort by the memory occupied?

Comment: sorry I didn't answer your question Friday, as I didn't have time to get on that server and repro.. besides, we had analyzed that already and didn't see anything (top usage was just framework stuff, not our dlls).

Comment: I saw your answer below. I had fixed a memory leak from GDI+ assembly by incorporating a WPF user control. Nevertheless, the point here was, that you need to hit the snapshot twice. Every hit calls GC.collect and subsequent hit pushes it out of finalizer queue. eg, I'll run the code once that leaks some memory, and suppose it was a form, i'll close it. hit snapshot twice. So the second hit should give me a more accurate value. Then to compare against this,i ll open the same form again and close and i'll hit snapshot twice again. Again the second one will give more accurate values.

Answer (score 0):

I was too quick to judge this. After I disabled most of the work that one page was doing, the growth stopped, but looking at other pages I saw a similar pattern, but it stopped at a lower memory limit, like say 450 meg.  then I upped our private memory limit to 2 gig instead of 1 gig, and re-enabled the "leaking" code. The memory shot up to 1.05 gig in 3 refreshes. 20 refreshes later, it is not significantly changing.

This is a case of IIS 64 bit app pool allocating way more memory than is necessary. Since it isn't actually leaking, this question was invalid.

anyway, if you notice the same behavior with Enable 32-bit Applications, I hope this helps you